# how to get the id from the clicked component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

On runtime, I create multiple instants of the Group class, like this:

```
var groupArtist:Group = new Group();
groupArtist.id = artistXML.id;
groupArtist.width = 150;
groupArtist.height = 170;
groupArtist.clipAndEnableScrolling = true;
groupArtist.layout = new VerticalLayout();
```

I add an eventlistener:

```
 groupArtist.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewDetails);
```

This is the eventlistener:

```
private function viewDetails(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Alert.show(event.target.id);
}
```

But it's not working. How can I get the id of the clicked Group?
I've checked, and the Id is added correctly to the groupinstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Alert.show(event.currentTarget.id);
```

What you're alerting is the "target" that was clicked, and associated in the "MouseEvent.CLICK" event, and you probably want the "currentTarget". [As Flex Documentation explains on this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html), "Every Event object has a **target** and a **currentTarget** property that help you to keep track of where it is in the process of propagation. The target property refers to the dispatcher of the event. **The currentTarget property refers to the current node that is being examined for event listeners.**".

The Most Interesting Man in the World doesn't normally code in Actionscript... but when he does, he uses event.currentTarget.

Comment: You're welcome! Awarding the right answer is a really nice way to say thanks too.

Comment: I know, but I had to wait 10 minutes until I could accept one.